# How to Query RDS Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I've looked all over, and yet I can't find anything on how to do this.

I created a DB instance on RDS using SQL Server Express Edition 13.00.4422.0.v1. I was able to connect using Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio and create and populate tables.

However, I have no idea how to run a query on a Microsoft SQL Server that is hosted on RDS - is it the same process as querying a MySQL server on RDS? Or is this just not possible?

Thanks!

Edit: I want to create a function in Lambda to be called on the API Gateway so I can query the database from a web application, I've been able to make queries on my PC from the Management Studio.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToMicrosoftSQLServerInstance.html

Answer (score 1):

You just do, if you are using MS SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO you shouldn't have any problems when running a query as it has buttons for pretty much anything including NEW QUERY.

In any case, check Amazon's documentation.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToMicrosoftSQLServerInstance.html

Comment: I think I wasn't specific enough - I want to make a function that can be put into the API Gateway and called from a web application.

Comment: @PeterFerrarotto You should probably delete this question then, and post a question specifically about querying SQL Server from an AWS Lambda function. Include what language you are writing the function with in the question.